# XTS-AES-128 and Grover's algorithm

Tags: aes, disk-encryption, post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptanalysis

AES-128 is considered weak against quantum computers because Grover's algorithm effectively halves its key length to unacceptable 64 bits.

XTS-AES-128 as described in IEEE 1619-2007 doubles key length to 256 bits by using distinct 128-bit keys for block and tweak encryption, which is sometimes remarked as unnecessary change to the original XEX construction.

https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/block-cipher-techniques/documents/bcm/comments/xts/xts_comments-liskov_minematsu.pdf

Grover's algorithm applied to XTS-AES-128 would attack the double-length 256 bit key, reducing it to 128 bits. Does it mean that the decision to use two keys for XTS-AES-128 made it reasonably resistant against quantum computers?

Comment: [Probably related](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30236/23623)