# What is the security of XTS block cipher mode of operation if the key is much larger than the block size?

Tags: block-cipher, key-size, blocksize, xts

I made two Linux kernel modules of Hasty Pudding Cipher with key size of 16896-bits (16384-bits key + 512-bits tweak also called "spice), one has 512-bits of block size, the other 128-bits.

I would like to use the 128-bits block size version with XTS in Linux, but I read [an answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30236/106219) here in the forum saying that AES-256 in XTS mode can be broken with less effort than brute-forcing the two 256-bits XTS keys together.

Two XTS keys of 16896-bits each would result in 33792-bits of key material, but what would be the effective security when using this large key size with a block size of only 128-bits?

Would the attack described in that [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/30236/106219) apply in this case?